# How to change "Add user" in the navbar of User Add Page of Django Admin?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on Django and I want to change the "Add user" in the navbar of the User Add Page as marked in the pic with some other text.

[image]

my admin.py file is this :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So it can be changed?? If yes then how??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What would you like to change it to and do you want to change it on every add page?

Comment: I want to customize my admin page according to me and yes I want the change to be on every add page

Comment: I have been noticing your questions for a while. Every post is "*similar*", how can I change this text, that text. I hope you have already got the idea of how to change different text representation in a form view (say *add form view*) in Django admin. I would say this is just a matter of commonsense. @Prince

Comment: @ArakkalAbu My questions might look similar but they are different and for every different text to be change we have to change some or the other block,and for customizing admin page it is necessary

Comment: You could ask these kinds of infinite (low quality) questions like "How to change text A?", text B, text C, in the same template/form. All these changes lie either in `add_form_template` or `change_form_template`

Comment: No some changes are made to change list page also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be changed.

And for that first add following line to your admin.py file :

```
add_form_template='add_form.html'
```

so your admin.py file becomes :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):


    add_form_template='add_form.html'


    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that go to templates folder and create a html file with name : `add_form.html` and add following code to it:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
&rsaquo; {% if has_view_permission %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %}
&rsaquo;


    {% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}


    Type here your new text instead of Add user


    {% endblocktrans %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Note: While typing the new text instead of "Add user" you can use `{{ name }}` to access the `verbose_name` of the model.

That's all you have to do.